# SQLite count performance

Tags: performance, sqlite, count

I'm experiencing (in my opinion) weird performance issues when trying to find the total number of records in a table. The (boiled down) table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "records" (
    pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    other_table_fk INTEGER,
    int_value INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(other_table_fk) REFERENCES other_table(pk)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
}

CREATE INDEX int_value_idx ON records(int_value);
```

Now when I try to query the count of all records this takes a long time:

```
$ time sqlite3 db.sqlite "SELECT count(ROWID) FROM records"
100000

real    0m2.962s
user    0m0.162s
sys     0m2.618s
```

When the indexed field is used the query is way faster (but the count is the same):

```
$ time sqlite3 db.sqlite "SELECT count(ROWID) FROM records WHERE records.int_value > 0"
100000

real    0m0.083s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.057s
```

My problem is, that the table schema is dependant on the users configuration, so I cannot be certain that I have an indexed field in the table, but I still want to have the performance of the indexed `COUNT`.

I know that primary keys have an index on their own, but in this case this does not seem to help:

```
$ time sqlite3 db.sqlite "SELECT count(ROWID) FROM records WHERE records.pk > 0"
100000

real    0m2.965s
user    0m0.138s
sys     0m2.636s
```

Weirdly, even *if* I create an additional index on the primary key, this does not help either:

```
$ time sqlite3 db.sqlite "CREATE INDEX records_pk_idx ON records(pk)"

real    0m3.288s
user    0m0.313s
sys     0m2.812s


$ time sqlite3 db.sqlite "SELECT count(ROWID) FROM records WHERE records.pk > 0"
100000

real    0m2.974s
user    0m0.154s
sys     0m2.624s
```

I read suggestions to circumvent this issue, either by using [`MAX(_ROWID_)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109826/746961) (not an option, as I do regular deletes) and using [triggers to store the number of records](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9338276/746961) (seems "dirty" to me to store redundant information).

Are there any other ways to speed up this seemingly trivial queries?

For the record:

```
$ sqlite3 -version
3.6.20
```

I'm stuck with this version.

EDIT:

As suggested by [CL.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11654/cl) the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` info:

```
$ sqlite3 db.sqlite "EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT count(ROWID) FROM records"
0|0|TABLE records

$ sqlite3 db.sqlite "EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT count(ROWID) FROM records WHERE records.pk < 0"
0|0|TABLE records USING PRIMARY KEY

$ sqlite3 db.sqlite "EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT count(ROWID) FROM records WHERE records. int_value > 0"
0|0|TABLE records WITH INDEX int_value_idx
```

This does not seem to add any additional information.

Comment: Why aren't you using `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: That was another try to improve performance (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20370767/746961) but that did not impact the performance significantly.

Comment: Most of that information is outdated. Use EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN to check what actually happens.

Comment: @CL.: edited the answer and added `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` output. The output seems rather obvious and I don't see how this helps me?

Comment: Counting without any index involved is slow. So the first and the third statement are slow. I wonder why it is still slow, when using the primary key. Is it the same, if you use `"records".pk` instead of `records.pk`? Note that the first version is case sensitive. I started a Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/48ee1/13. But it doesn't help to explain why execution with `pk` is slow.

Comment: @Trinimon: Unfortunately using `"records".pk` instead of `records.pk` did not have an impact on execution time. Thanks for the sqlfiddle, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite: COUNT slow on big tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988915/sqlite-count-slow-on-big-tables)