# sqlite painfully slow querying even with index

Tags: performance, sqlite

I have a very trivial database with a single table:

```
CREATE TABLE records ( 
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    symbol VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 

    time_ts INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    open_ts INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    close_ts INTEGER NOT NULL, 

    open_price REAL NOT NULL,
    high_price REAL NOT NULL,
    low_price REAL NOT NULL,
    close_price REAL NOT NULL,

    trades_count INTEGER NOT NULL,

    volume_amount REAL NOT NULL,
    quote_asset_volume REAL NOT NULL,
    taker_buy_base_asset_volume REAL NOT NULL,
    taker_buy_quote_asset_volume REAL NOT NULL)
```

and an index:

```
CREATE INDEX symbol_index ON records (symbol)
```

A size of a database is `12.63GB`.

I am running this query:

```
SELECT 
    symbol, 
    MAX(close_ts) max_close_ts, 
    MIN(close_ts) min_close_ts 
FROM records 
GROUP BY symbol
```

And it takes about a **minute** to execute it.

As you see, an index is created on `symbol` column.. However, even with this - the querying is painfully slow..

Even a query like:

```
select count(id) from records;
```

Takes about 77 seconds to execute. Total number of rows in table is `115_944_904`.

I expect the record count to be increased twice in the future. Is there anything I can do to make queries work faster? Even with indexes on primary key and on a symbol column I am getting quite bad performance..

Have I hit a limit of any kind?

Comment: For future reference, the sqlite3 command line shell has a feature that can suggest indexes to add for a given query: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#index_recommendations_sqlite_expert_

Comment: Also a good idea to run [ANALYZE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) on a table after adding indexes, and [PRAGMA optimize](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_optimize) just before closing a database to regenerate statistics if needed.

Comment: Finally, see if `select count(*) from records;` is faster than explicitly listing a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create covering index to avoid accessing table:

```
CREATE INDEX symbol_index ON records (symbol,close_ts)

SELECT 
    symbol, 
    MAX(close_ts) max_close_ts, 
    MIN(close_ts) min_close_ts 
FROM records 
GROUP BY symbol;
```

Comment: now it takes ~11 seconds for the same query with a group. Are there any ways to increase a simple query `select count(id) from records;` performance? I find it hard to believe that counting of number of records should be that slow..

Comment: @Alex here's an answer on another question that describes why count(*) is so slow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9338276/246901

Answer (score 1):

Should use the "EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN"and see the scan statistics,It will also show whetehr the index created by you is using the index. Also you should create covering indices "https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx" for better performance.

Example:
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
select count(id) from records;

Answer (score 1):

As Lukasz Szozda said the index

```
CREATE INDEX symbol_index ON records (symbol,close_ts)
```

should make your query faster, because you have two aggregate statement on each group.

This way, the DMBS will skip all the intermediate rows for each different entry in the symbol column.

The advantage you will take will be proportional to the symbols: less different symbol column entry you'll have, the more will be the speed increase of the query